# which list element is being processed when using snowfall::sfLapply?

Tags: list, r, parallel-processing, apply, lapply

Assume we have a list (`mylist`) that is use as input object for a `lapply` function. Is there a way to know which element in `mylist` is being evaluated? The method should work on `lapply` and `snowfall::sfApply` (and possible others apply family members) as well.

On [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106/r), Gavin Simpson suggested the following method. This works great for `lapply` but not so much for `sfApply`. I would like to avoid extra packages or fiddling with the list. Any suggestions?

```
mylist <- list(a = 1:10, b = 1:10)
foo <- function(x) {
    deparse(substitute(x))
}
bar <- lapply(mylist, FUN = foo)

> bar
$a
[1] "X[[1L]]"

$b
[1] "X[[2L]]"
```

This is the parallel version that isn't cutting it.

```
library(snowfall)
sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 2, type = "SOCK") # I use 2 cores

sfExport("foo", "mylist")
bar.para <- sfLapply(x = mylist, fun = foo)

> bar.para
$a
[1] "X[[1L]]"

$b
[1] "X[[1L]]"

sfStop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are going to have to use Shane's solution/suggestion in that chat session. Store your objects in a list such that each component of the top list contains a component with the name or ID or experiment contained in that list component, plus a component containing the object you want to process:

```
obj <- list(list(ID = 1, obj = 1:10), list(ID = 2, obj = 1:10), 
            list(ID = 3, obj = 1:10), list(ID = 4, obj = 1:10),
            list(ID = 5, obj = 1:10))
```

So we have the following structure:

```
> str(obj)
List of 5
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ ID : num 1
  ..$ obj: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ ID : num 2
  ..$ obj: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ ID : num 3
  ..$ obj: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ ID : num 4
  ..$ obj: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ ID : num 5
  ..$ obj: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

The have something like the first line in the following function, followed by your

```
foo <- function(x) {
    writeLines(paste("Processing Component:", x$ID))
    sum(x$obj)
}
```

Which will do this:

```
> res <- lapply(obj, foo)
Processing Component: 1
Processing Component: 2
Processing Component: 3
Processing Component: 4
Processing Component: 5
```

Which might work on snowfall.

Answer (score 2):

I could also alter the attributes like so.

```
mylist <- list(a = 1:10, b = 1:10)
attr(mylist[[1]], "seq") <- 1
attr(mylist[[2]], "seq") <- 2

foo <- function(x) {
    writeLines(paste("Processing Component:", attributes(x)))   
}
bar <- lapply(mylist, FUN = foo)
```

(and the parallel version)

```
mylist <- list(a = 1:10, b = 1:10)
attr(mylist[[1]], "seq") <- 1
attr(mylist[[2]], "seq") <- 2

foo <- function(x) {
    x <- paste("Processing Component:", attributes(x))  
}
sfExport("mylist", "foo")
bar <- sfLapply(mylist, fun = foo)
```

Comment: That looked "wrong" and sure enough, when I try `attr(mylist[[1]]) <- 1`, I get: `Error in `attr<-`(`*tmp*`, value = 2) : 
  2 arguments passed to 'attr<-' which requires 3`. I think you need to specify a name for the attribute

Comment: @BondedDust funny, I don't recall this one NOT working. I edited the two offending lines.