# Identify which element is being processed when using *apply functions

Tags: r

Presumably R knows which member of a list, or element of a vector, or row of matrix, etc. it is processing while running an *apply function.  Is it possible to use this index in the function, without resorting to some workaround like this:

```
fruit <- c("Bananas", "Oranges", "Avocados", "Celeries?")
sapply(fruit, function(x) 
   paste(x, "are fruit number", which(fruit==x)))
```

or other workarounds such as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164960/which-list-element-is-being-processed-when-using-snowfallsflapply) posted in reference to a similar question?

Hoping [fruitlessly?] for something more elegant.

Comment: You could give `fruit` attributes and call that from within the `apply` (family) function. See usage of that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164960/which-list-element-is-being-processed-when-using-snowfallsflapply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd rather write

```
sapply(seq_along(fruit), function(ii) paste(fruit[ii], "are fruit number", ii))
```

Comment: Is `seq_along()` essentially just short-hand for `1:length(fruit)`? The advantage then, being, that `seq_along` is `primitive` and therefore fast.  But in the end does this not just makes the *apply into a slightly more explicit `for` loop?  I guess I am hoping for too much from my convenience loop functions, and should rather try to vectorize!

Comment: And he would have gotten away with it if it weren't for those meddling kids.

Comment: `seq_along` is a bit more robust too, try `fruit = c(); seq_along(fruit); 1:length(fruit)`. I agree that a `for` loop is a valid choice, whichever is more legible in a given situation would have my preference.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass an index instead of the vector to sapply;

```
fruit <- c("Bananas", "Oranges", "Avocados", "Celeries?")
sapply(seq_along(fruit), function(x) paste(fruit[x], "are fruit number", x))
```

Comment: Beat by 30 seconds by baptise

Comment: Pick fruit with shorter names next time :-)

Comment: I am disappointed that nobody noticed that celery are not fruit, but stems.

Comment: Funny I ran through this so quickly my brain registered as Cherries.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps mapply is a useful alternative? (not really needed here though)

```
fruit <- c("Bananas", "Oranges", "Avocados", "Celeries?")
mapply(paste, fruit, "are fruit number", seq_along(fruit))
```