# Why are variable values in closures getting lost after repeatedly calling lapply?

Tags: r, scope, closures, currying, lapply

I'm attempting to use a series of `lapply` calls to build a list of curried functions, which ideally at the last `lapply` call, returns the final desired value. The currying works, but `lapply` seems to always applies the last element in the list after the second application.

Example:

```
curry <- function(fn, ...) {
  arglist <- list(...)
  function(...) {
    do.call(fn, append(arglist, list(...)))
  }
}
# rcurry is used only to init the first lapply.
rcurry <- function(v1, fn, ...) {
  arglist <- append(list(v1), list(...))
  function(...) {
    do.call(fn, append(arglist, list(...)))
  }
}

myadd <- function(a,b,c) {
  a+b+c
}
```

This works as expected:

```
# you can achieve the same by closure:
# curry.a <- lapply(c(10, 1000), FUN = function(a) { curry(myadd, a) })
curry.a <- lapply(list(10, 1000), rcurry, myadd)
curry.a[[1]](1,2)
curry.a[[2]](1,2)

# > [1] 13
# > [1] 1003
```

The next `lapply` of `curry` "mangles the scope":

```
# this does give the desired output:
# curry.a.b <- list(curry(curry.a[[1]], 1), curry(curry.a[[2]], 1))
curry.a.b <- lapply(curry.a, curry, 1)
curry.a.b[[1]](2)
curry.a.b[[2]](2)

# > [1] 1003
# > [1] 1003
```

It doesn't seem like a result of the `curry` or `rcurry` function. Using `roxygen`'s `Curry` function does the same thing. creating `curry.a` by closure above or using `curry.a <- list(curry(myadd, 10), curry(myadd, 1000))` also results the same.

And of course the final curry:

```
# it doesn't work if you re-define this:
# curry.a.b <- list(curry(curry.a[[1]], 1), curry(curry.a[[2]], 2))
curry.a.b.c <- lapply(curry.a.b, curry, 2)
lapply(curry.a.b.c, do.call, list())

# > [1] 1003
# > [1] 1003
```

What's going on here?

Comment: `lapply` evaluates `FUN` in a new environment.  I think that has something to do with it.

Comment: I think the answer is the same as in Tommy's reply to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950144/access-lapply-index-names-inside-fun/9950734#comment12707459_9950734

Comment: Joshua is warm, kohske nails it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fn` in `curry` is not evaluated in the scope of function and hence it is `promise`.
If you `force` it then you can get what you expect:

```
curry <- function(fn, ...) {
  force(fn)
  arglist <- list(...)
  function(...) {
    do.call(fn, append(arglist, list(...)))
  }
}
```

then,

```
> curry.a.b <- lapply(curry.a, curry, 1)
> curry.a.b[[1]](2)
[1] 13
> curry.a.b[[2]](2)
[1] 1003
> 
> curry.a.b.c <- lapply(curry.a.b, curry, 2)
> lapply(curry.a.b.c, do.call, list())
[[1]]
[1] 13

[[2]]
[1] 1003
```

More internally, `lapply` generates a local variable `X` that is referred by each call of function. If `X` is not evaluated in each function when calling the `lapply`, `X` is promise. After calling `lapply`, `X` in all function call from `lapply` returns same (i.e., last) value. So `lapply` is similar with:

```
f0 <- function(i) function() i
f1 <- function(i) {force(i); function() i}

f <- local({
 r0 <- list()
 r1 <- list()
 for (i in 1:2) {
    r0[[i]] <- f0(i)
    r1[[i]] <- f1(i)
 }
 list(r0 = r0, r1 = r1)
})
```

then,

```
> f$r0[[1]]()
[1] 2
> f$r1[[1]]()
[1] 1
> f$r0[[2]]()
[1] 2
> f$r1[[2]]()
[1] 2
```

Comment: 100% Bulls eye. Thank you! I actually thought the closure is the promise, so I did `closure <- function(...) { do.call(fn, append(arglist, list(...)) }; force(closure); return closure`. Of course, that didn't work.