# deparse(substitute(x)) in lapply?

Tags: r, lapply, substitution

I would like use a function that uses the standard `deparse(substitute(x))` trick within `lapply`. Unfortunately I just get the argument of the loop back. Here's my completely useless reproducible example:

```
# some test data
a <- 5
b <- 6 
li <- list(a1=a,b2=b)

# my test function
tf <- function(obj){
nm <- deparse(substitute(obj))
res <- list(myName=nm)
res
}

tf(a)
#returns
$myName
[1] "a"
```

which is fine. If I use `lapply` I either get `[[1L]]` or the `x` argument of an anonymous function.

```
lapply(li,function(x) tf(x))
# returns
$a1
$a1$myName
[1] "x"


$b2
$b2$myName
[1] "x"
```

Is there any way to obtain the following?

```
$a1
$a1$myName
[1] "a1"


$b2
$b2$myName
[1] "b1"
```

If there's anything more general on `deparse(substitute(x))` and `lapply` I'd also eager to know.

EDIT: 
The problem as opposed to using an anonymous function that accepts multiple arguments and can thus use the name of the object and the object itself does not work because, the `tf` function will only accept one argument. So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950144/access-lapply-index-names-inside-fun/9950734#9950734) does not work here...

Comment: As with most of R, `lapply` passes the values to functions, not the variable references.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer James, I guess I was able to find something comparable here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950144/access-lapply-index-names-inside-fun/9950734#9950734 . I will check it and either delete this questions as a duplicate or add an answer as soon as I am able to answer my own question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution :

```
lapply(li, function(x) {
  call1 <-  sys.call(1)
  call1[[1]] <- as.name("names")
  call1 <- call1[1:2]
  nm <- eval(call1)
  y <- deparse(substitute(x))
  y <- gsub("\\D", "", y)
  y <- as.numeric(y)
  list(myname=nm[y])
})
```

Comment: Very clever way to get the call. Your function can be simplified to this: `lapply(li, function(x)names(eval(sys.call(1)[[2]]))[substitute(x)[[3]]])`. Note that `sys.call(1)[[2]]` returns the symbol or expression used as the list argument to `lapply`, and `substitute(x)[[3]]` returns the current index in the loop.

Comment: I really your way but at each iteration you will have to call the object (eval(sys.call(1))) instead of object's names. Could it be less powerful with large objects?

Comment: `eval(sys.call(1)[[2]])` will result in a symbol usually, `li` in this case, and probably does not cause duplication of the object it references, since this is passed to `names` which is a primitive function. As an alternative, you can save the names `nm <- names(li)` first and then use `lapply(li, function(x)nm[substitute(x)[[3]]])`.