# Rename the Second Column in a List of Data Frames using the Name of the Data Frame (deparse, substitute, and lapply)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rename, lapply

**Sample Data**

I have a list of data frames with two columns each: 1. variable names, 2. integers.

```
df3 <- df2 <- df1 <- data.frame(Variable = LETTERS[1:5], Value = sample(10:20, 5, replace = TRUE))
df.list <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)
df.list

# $df1
#     Variable Value
# 1        A    17
# 2        B    16
# 3        C    16
# 4        D    18
# 5        E    10
#
# $df2
#     Variable Value
# 1        A    17
# ...
```

**What I Want to Do**

Each data frame in the list is named. I want to extract the name of the data frame and use it to rename the second column in that data frame:

```
# $df1
#     Variable df1
# 1        A    17
# 2        B    16
# 3        C    16
# 4        D    18
# 5        E    10
#
# $df2
#     Variable df2
# 1        A    17
# ...
```

**What I've Tried**

I've written a function to do this using `deparse(substitute()` and regular expression pattern matching via `sub()`:

```
mod.name <- function(x) {
    nx <- deparse(substitute(x))
    ny <- sub(".*\\$", "", nx)
    names(x)[2] <- ny
    x
}
```

When tested on a single data frame in the list, it works:

```
mod.name(df.list$df3)
df.list$df3

# Variable df3
# 1  A     17
# 2  B     16
# 3  C     16
# 4  D     18
# 5  E     10
```

However, when using `lapply` to do it on all the data frames in the list, it does not:

```
lapply(df.list, mod.name)
df.list

# $df1
#    Variable  X[[i]]
# 1        A     17
# 2        B     16
# 3        C     16
# 4        D     18
# 5        E     10
#
# $df2
#    Variable  X[[i]]
# 1        A    17
# ...
```

Of course, the issue of using `deparse(substitute()` with `lapply()` has been discussed before on StackOverflow, but I could not get any of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508790/deparsesubstitutex-in-lapply), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897684/deparsesubstitutex-in-lapply), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950144/access-lapply-index-names-inside-fun?noredirect=1&lq=1) to work for me.

Comment: `Map(function(x,y){ names(y)[[2]] <- x; y }, names(df.list), df.list)` but this is a bad idea.

Comment: @Frank That works--thanks! But can you expound on why it's a bad idea?

Comment: Sure. Embedding a variable (the 1,2,3 in df1, df2, df3) as part of a column name means you'll have to parse that column name again later. Also, retaining a list of data.frames with related contents instead of using `rbind` to make a single one will continue to cause messiness (requiring more `lapply` or `mapply` instead of normal table operations). Gregor discusses tradeoffs involved in a list vs a single table here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/ and Hadley discusses putting vars in col names here: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10

Comment: So in this case, I'd do `data.table::rbindlist(df.list, id="src")` (mentioned in Gregor's post).

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the explanation. That's good to know. In this specific case, my goal was to extract the newly named second columns and `cbind` them into a new data frame to more easily compare how the values change for the variables listed in the first column, but perhaps it would be better to `rbind` it first and then reshape from long two wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, this works for the stated goal:

```
Map(function(x,y){ names(y)[[2]] <- x; y }, names(df.list), df.list)
```

The OP said their eventual goal was to `cbind` the columns together (presumably since the `Variable` column is identical in all the tables), so here are some other ideas.

**`rbind` and reshape.** To get there, if all the variables are of the same type (e.g., integer or float), I would just store the data in long form:

```
library(data.table)
DT = rbindlist(df.list, id = "src")

    src Variable Value
 1: df1        A    17
 2: df1        B    11
 3: df1        C    20
 4: df1        D    10
 5: df1        E    19
 6: df2        A    17
 7: df2        B    11
 8: df2        C    20
 9: df2        D    10
10: df2        E    19
11: df3        A    17
12: df3        B    11
13: df3        C    20
14: df3        D    10
15: df3        E    19
```

From there, you can go back to wide format with

```
dcast(DT, Variable ~ src)

   Variable df1 df2 df3
1:        A  17  17  17
2:        B  11  11  11
3:        C  20  20  20
4:        D  10  10  10
5:        E  19  19  19
```

**`cbind`.** If the columns have different types, they could be brought together with

```
as.data.table(c(df.list[[1]][1], lapply(df.list, `[`, -1)))

   Variable df1.Value df2.Value df3.Value
1:        A        17        17        17
2:        B        11        11        11
3:        C        20        20        20
4:        D        10        10        10
5:        E        19        19        19
```

If you're using data.table like this, `setnames` can be used to change the column names afterwards.

---

The OP mentioned both ideas in comments. I'm just illustrating the code details.

Either way, I think sticking to one table will be easier for later analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `deparse(substitute(.))`.

```
nms <- setNames(, names(df.list))
df.list2 <- lapply(nms, function(x){
        names(df.list[[x]])[2] <- x
        df.list[[x]]
    })
df.list2
```

**EDIT**
Following a suggestion of Frank in the comment below, I have changed `nms <- names(df.list)` to `nms <- setNames(, names(df.list))`, and the name of the output list to `df.list2`.

Comment: @Frank Right, thanks, I'll remember that. And edit the answer.