# Passing dataframe by name to lapply, modifying and using the name, and saving the results

Tags: r

I am trying to loop through a list of data frames in the global environment. I want to extract the variable name, substring the variable name, filter (tidyverse) each dataframe, and then save each filtered dataframe. However, I'm having quite a bit of trouble:

```
query_loop <- function(df){

    name <- deparse(substitute(df));
    cpt <- paste("cpt_","20", substring(name, 14, 15), sep = "");
    assign(cpt, filter(df, CPT == "12345"));
    write.table(cpt, file = paste(deparse(substitute(cpt)), ".txt", sep =""), row.names = F, sep = "\t");
}
```

`dfs1 <- lapply(dfs, query_loop)`

The code fails at the first step of my function. When I try to `print(deparse(substitute(df)))`, I get a list of X[[i]], which I understand is because the dataframes are not named when I pass them to lapply. However, I don't know what the correct solution is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `names(dfs)` is a character vector, so `df` in your function is a length-1 character vector with the name of the current data frame. Normally one uses `deparse(substitute())` to get a string--you already have a string.

Comment: The _correct_ solution is not to have all your data frames in the global environment, but in a list. How does `names(df)` return the names of data frames in your global environment? If you already have the names of all the data frames, you can use `mget` to obtain all those data frames in a list

Comment: Sorry, I posted my code wrong. I am passing in ```dfs``` into lapply, which is a list of the dataframes. The rest of my question is correct, i.e. when I try to print(deparse(substitute(df))), it prints out X[[i]] 6 times (the number of dataframes in the list)

Comment: So... is your `list` named? If so, use the names of the list as your code shows. If not, name the list and use the names of the list as your code shows.

Comment: Otherwise [there's this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18511080/903061) (and I would close your question as a duplicate of that one), but working with the names seems much easier.

Comment: Is there a way to name the lists programmatically? I created the ```dfs``` list using this code: ```dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested simplification (untested, obviously, as there's no data to test on).

```
## assumption: `dfs` is a named list of data frames

# create a list of filtered data frames with appropriate names
filtered_list = lapply(dfs, filter, CPT == "12345")
names(filtered_list) = paste0("cpt_","20", substring(names(dfs), 14, 15))

# write them to files
lapply(names(filtered_list), function(nm) {
  write.table(
    x = filtered_list[[nm]],
    file = paste0(nm, ".txt"),
    row.names = F, sep = "\t")
})
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked. However, is there a way to programmatically name all the data frame elements of dfs list? I first loaded several data frames into the global environment, and I would like to name the data frame elements of the list using the global environment variable names. I loaded them using ```Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))```. Also, after I run the code you provided above, the console outputs ```[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL

[[6]]
NULL``` Is there a reason why?

Comment: The NULLs are there because `write.table` returns NULL. You can stop the printing by adding a `invisible()` as the last line of `function(nm)`. As for the naming, I'd strongly suggest loading the data frames directly into a list, not the global environment. [See my answer at How to make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) for examples and discussion.

Comment: But I'm also confused that you don't have names, because when I run your code`x = Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))`, and I look at `names(x)`, `x` does have the names of the global environment variables.

Comment: That's weird. The way I have been loading the dataframes is by doing: ```temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt")``` , then ```for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.delim(temp[i]))```, then ```dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))```. I will try to load the files into a named list next time.

Comment: You should do `temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt"); data_list = lapply(temp, read.delim); names(data_list) = temp`

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try next time. Thanks!

Comment: Or, if you use `purrr` you can skeip the `names()` step: `data_list = purrr::map_dfr(temp, read.delim)`.