# Extract listed data frame names inside lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply, names

I am creating a list of plots from a list of data frames and am trying to add a title to each plot corresponding to the name of the data frame in the list.
Outside of `lapply` if I call `paste0(names(df.list)[x])` it returns the name of the data frame of interest.

When I try and add this within `lapply`

`df.plots<-lapply(df.list, function(x) 
  p<-ggplot(x,aes(x=Numbers,y=Signal)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(paste0(names(df.list)[x]))
)`

I get the following error:

`Error in names(df.list)[x] : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Is there another way I can extract the data frames names so I can add them to the plots?

Comment: If all the elements of the list are named, I think adding `ggtitle(names(x))` should suffice.

Comment: Related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950144/access-lapply-index-names-inside-fun) in terms of lapply and named list elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map2` from *purrr* to loop through the list and the names of the list simultaneously, creating a plot each time.  In `map2`, the `.x` refers to the first list and `.y` refer to the second list, which you can use in your plotting code.

```
library(purrr)
map2(dlist, names(dlist), 
    ~ggplot(.x, aes(Numbers, Signal)) +
        geom_point() +
        ggtitle(.y))
```

Answer (score 1):

This fails because the value of `x` is an element of the list `df.list`, which isn't something you can use to index a vector of names.

You could try `lapply` on an indexing vector instead, which is explained in the question aosmith linked ([Access lapply index names inside FUN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950144/access-lapply-index-names-inside-fun))

```
lapply(seq_along(df.list), function(i) {
    ggplot(df_list[[i]], aes(x=Numbers, y=Signal)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      ggtitle(names(df.list)[i])
}
```

(Also, not your directly related to your question, but calling `paste0` doesn't do anything if you pass it just a single value, so you can drop that)