# outputting element names of list of lists within lapply

Tags: r, lapply

Passing names (or indicies) to `lapply` allows the element name to be accessed within the function (as per the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950144/access-lapply-index-names-inside-fun)). How can the same approach be applied to deal with lists of lists?

In the example below, each list element ("A" and "B") is itself a list, containing multiple named dataframes ("df_001" and so on).

```
list_of_lists <- list("A" = list("df_001" = data.frame(X = 1, Y = 1), "df_002" = data.frame(X = 1, Y = 2), "df_003" = data.frame(X = 2, Y = 1)),
                      "B" = list("df_004" = data.frame(X = 1, Y = 1), "df_005" = data.frame(X = 1, Y = 2), "df_006" = data.frame(X = 2, Y = 1)))
```

I'd like to apply, to each of these dataframes, a function which can paste both its dataframe name (e.g. "df_001") and its parent list name (e.g. "A"). For example, generate a plot for each dataframe with a title alike "A: df_001" or "B: df_004" etc

I can do so for each seperate list element ("A" or "B"), as below

```
plot_with_name <- function(z) {
  dat <- list_of_lists[["A"]][[z]]
  plot(dat[, 1], dat[, 2],
       main = paste("A: ", z) )
}
lapply( names(list_of_lists[["A"]]), plot_with_name )
# then repeat, replacing "A" with "B"
```

but I'm curious as to whether this can be done without needing to split the list.

My proto-idea is to use a nested `lapply` call. The attempt below applies a function to all dataframes, but does not call the names. Perhaps it can be modified to do so (?)

```
lapply( list_of_lists, lapply, function(x) { plot(x[, 1],x[, 2]) } ) # generates plots WITHOUT names
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is a bit of a work-around, but how about: `ul <- unlist(list_of_lists, rec=FALSE); Map(function(d,n) plot(d[,1],d[,2], main=n), ul, names(ul))` ?

Comment: Another work-around: `library(data.table); library(ggplot2); ggplot(melt(list_of_lists), aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~interaction(L1, L2))`

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions. i've chosen @Chirayu's as the solution, though I appreciate it's by and large equivalent to the `Map()` suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to thelatemail anwser:

```
xx=unlist(list_of_lists, recursive=FALSE)
mapply(plot, x = xx, main = names(xx), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
nms_list <- names(list_of_lists)    

for (i in seq_along(nms_list)) {
  m <- length(list_of_lists[[nms_list[i]]])
  for (l in 1:m) {
    dat <- list_of_lists[[nms_list[i]]][[l]]
    plot(dat[, 1], dat[, 2],
       main = paste(nms_list[i],":",  names(list_of_lists[[nms_list[i]]])[l]))
  }
}
```