# Print out the name of a list in list in R?

Tags: r, list

Sorry for the cryptic headline.

However, it is rather simple. I have a list that contains several lists, for example:

```
list1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
list2 <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
list3 <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

dataset <- list(list1, list2, list3)
```

So if I wanna do some looping with this It could look like:

```
for (data in dataset) {
    mean(data)
}
```

However, depending on the number of lists inside the dataset list one might to know which list the calculated mean belongs to. So in principle I would like it to say:

```
for (data in dataset) {
    print(name-of-list-inside-dataset-list)
    mean(data)
}
```

Can this be done, or...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access lapply index names inside FUN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950144/access-lapply-index-names-inside-fun)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the names of the list elements:
Shamelessly stolen from @Hanjo Jo'burg Odendaal

```
dataset <- list("one" = list1, "two" = list2, "three" = list3)
```

Then print the name and mean: (no packages needed and lightning fast)

```
lapply(seq_along(dataset),function(x){
    paste("Name:", names(dataset[x]),"Mean:", mean(dataset[[x]]))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, all you have to do is name the list:

```
list1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
list2 <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
list3 <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

dataset <- list("one" = list1, "two" = list2, "three" = list3)

names(dataset)
```

My suggestion would be to use `purrr` code for your problem:

```
library(purrr)
dataset %>% map(mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good use for the `lapply` and `names` functions. `lapply` conveniently applies the same function to each element of a list, thus bypassing a `for` loop.

```
list1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
list2 <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
list3 <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

dataset <- list(list1, list2, list3)
names(dataset) <- c("list1", "list2", "list3")

lapply(dataset, mean)
$list1
[1] 5.5

$list2
[1] 6.5

$list3
[1] 7.5
```