# making and naming multiple decision tree plots with a user defined function

Tags: r

I'd like to build decision trees for multiple data sets, so to make life easier I'd like to make a UDF.

I'm using the cu.summary data set from rpart() for my MWE. Mileage is predicted by price, country, reliability, and type.

I've borrowed code (from https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html) that works well when modelling a single data frame like cu.summary.

Continuing with cu.summary, I split it into two data frames, cu.summaryADC and cu.summaryNJD. I then tried to pass cu.summaryADC and cu.summaryNJD into my UDF function to make my decision trees.

The problem's the title of the decision trees. I'd like the title of the plot to include the name of the data frame used to generate it, eg "Regression Tree for Mileage cu.summaryADC" and "Regression Tree for Mileage cu.summaryNJD".

My attempt at a general expression `main= paste("Regression Tree for Mileage ", names(DTList))` doesn't work.

Thanks for any help!

Attempt at code for multiple data frames:

```
#LOAD PACKAGE 
library(rpart)

# PREPARE MWE DATA BY SPLITTING IT INTO TWO DATA FRAMES   
dflist <- split(cu.summary, rep(1:2, length.out = nrow(cu.summary), each = ceiling(nrow(cu.summary)/2)))
cu.summaryADC <- dflist[[1]]
cu.summaryNJD <- dflist[[2]]

# MAKE FUNCTION 
DTMakerFun <- function(x){
fit <- rpart(Mileage~Price + Country + Reliability + Type, 
               method="anova", data=x)
  fitplot <- plot(fit, uniform=TRUE, 
                  main= paste("Regression Tree for Mileage ", names(DTList)))
  text(fit, use.n=TRUE, all=TRUE, cex=.8)
  return(fitplot)
}

# APPLY FUNCTION 
DTList <- lapply(list(cu.summaryADC,cu.summaryNJD), DTMakerFun)
```

Comment: `DTList` doesn't exists so it can't really get any name from there?

Comment: I think [this is what you're after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950144/access-lapply-index-names-inside-fun).