# How to set ggplot x-label equal to variable name during lapply?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply, tidyeval, nse

I'm making plots of one y variable against multiple x variables.
I have a working solution using lapply. However, I can't manage to write the name of the x variable as the x label for each plot. Here's a simplified example of what I have:

The goal is to plot the y variable against each x variable resulting in three plots and adding the name of each x variable as the x axis label.

*Generate a dataframe with one y variable and three x variables:*

```
df <- data.frame(y.variable=c(11:20), x1=c(21:30),x2=c(1:10),x3=c(31:40))
```

*A function that is supposed to retrieve the variable name as a string:*

```
get_name <- function(v1) {deparse(substitute(v1))}
```

*The function that generates the plot of y against an x variable:*

```
generate_plot <- function(x.variable) {ggplot(data = df, aes(x.variable, y.variable )) +geom_point()  + xlab(get_name(variable.name))}
```

*A call to lapply to perform generate_plot on each column of df:*

```
lapply(df, generate_plot)
```

This results in three plots, each of which has "variable.x" as its x-label instead of the desired variable name x1, x2 and x3.

Comment: `lapply` can't access the names of the list you pass it. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9950217/4738478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modify your `generate_plot` a little bit and use the version of [`ggplot2`](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-3-0-0/) (`> v3.0.0`) which supports `tidy evaluation`

Explanation:

- Inside the function, we use `rlang::sym` to turn a string into a symbol then `unquote` it inside `aes` using `!!` (bang bang)
- To call the function, use `purrr::map` to loop through `df` column names

See more:

- https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html
- http://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quotation.html

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(y.variable=c(11:20), 
                 x1=c(21:30), x2=c(1:10), x3=c(31:40))

generate_plot2 <- function(df, x.variable) {
  x.variable <- rlang::sym(x.variable)

  ggplot(data = df, aes(!! x.variable, y.variable )) +
    geom_point() + 
    xlab(x.variable)
}

names(df)[-1] %>% 
  map(~ generate_plot2(df, .x))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-04-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).</sup>

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for your help !
I think I understand the use of rlang::sym and !! in aes. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the graph in the image below with by copy-pasting the code you provided. I get the following error: "Error in !x.variable : invalid argument type"

Comment: You need the development version of `ggplot2`. See that line of code in my answer. Make sure to restart `R` before installing

Comment: You're right. I didn't install the development version of ggplot2.
Works like a charm right now.. thanks !