# replace magrittr operator pipe (%>%) with "+" in ggplot call

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I am trying to modify this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51239178/4083743) which automatically labels `ggplot` objects so that it is more flexible and follows `ggplot` syntax (so uses `+`) so I can just add a call to the end of a `ggplot` call. Essentially I am trying to replace a magrittr operator pipe `%>%` with `+`.

```
library(tidyverse)
ir <- data.frame(sp = iris$Species, sep.len = iris$Sepal.Length,
                 sep.wid = iris$Sepal.Width, pet.len = iris$Petal.Length,
                 pet.wid = iris$Petal.Width)
my_labels <- c("sp" = "species", 
               "sep.len" = "sepal length", 
               "sep.wid" = "sepal width",
               "pet.len" = "petal length", 
               "pet.wid" = "petal width")

# function to automatically label ggplot object
add_ggplot_label <- function(my_ggplot, l) {
  my_ggplot$labels <- lapply(my_ggplot$labels, function(x) {
    as.character(l[x])
  })
  my_ggplot
}

p <- ggplot(ir, aes(x = sep.len, y = sep.wid, col = sp)) + 
  geom_point() 
p

# apply function via pipe magrittr operator which automates the labelling
p %>% 
  add_ggplot_label(., my_labels)
```

[image]

This works well but it means I need to assign it to an object name first (i.e. `p`). So, for example, this doesn't work:

```
ggplot(ir, aes(x = sep.len, y = sep.wid, col = sp)) + 
  geom_point() %>% 
  add_ggplot_label(., my_labels)
```

I would need to remember to wrap it in brackets each time for this to work:

```
(ggplot(ir, aes(x = sep.len, y = sep.wid, col = sp)) + 
    geom_point()) %>% 
  add_ggplot_label(., my_labels)
```

Even still, its not exactly what I want. Ideally I want a more `ggplot` like workflow. Something like this, note `+` (not `%>%`):

```
ggplot(ir, aes(x = sep.len, y = sep.wid, col = sp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  add_ggplot_label(my_labels)
```

Of course this doesn't work as `+` and `%>%` are not interchangeable in its current format. To use `+`, I think i would need to take a different approach and add a layer and access the names within the call:

```
# add a layer
labs_addition <- function() {
  list(labs(x = my_labels[.$labels$x],
            y = my_labels[.$labels$y],
            colour = my_labels[.$labels$colour]))
}
ggplot(ir, aes(x = sep.len, y = sep.wid, col = sp)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs_addition()
```

This doesn't work and I am not sure if it is possible to reference what has been made previously upstream in the way I am attempting?

Any suggestions please?

thanks

Comment: IIRC, the `+`-overloading done by `ggplot2` works because the LHS of the addition is what drives the addition; which means `ggplot2:::+.gg` needs to know what to do with the RHS. This is find, so long as the RHS doesn't need anything from the LHS. This is possibly one reason Hadley (author of `ggplot2`) at one point posted a "regret" of sorts about overloading `+`, the RHS has no awareness of state.

Comment: You _might_ be able to fake a `geom` (inheriting some ggproto properties/methods) to try some in-place mods on the object, but that gg-ninja-fu is out of my wheelhouse ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really have to do a bit of hacking to get this to work, but you can create your own class and then customize the `ggplot_add` method for that class. We can define some helpers

```
as_ggfun <- function(fn) {
  structure(list(fun=fn), class="ggfun")
}
ggplot_add.ggfun <- function(object, p, objectname) {
  object$fun(p)
}
```

Then you need your `add_ggplot_label` function to return a `ggfun` object. For example

```
add_ggplot_label <- function(l) {
  as_ggfun(function(p) {
    p$labels <- lapply(p$labels, function(x) {
      as.character(l[x])
    })
    p
  })
}
```

Then you can call

```
ggplot(ir, aes(x = sep.len, y = sep.wid, col = sp)) + 
  geom_point() +
  add_ggplot_label(my_labels)
```

and have it all "work". I wouldn't necessarily recommend this. It would probably be better to just create a helper function to build the correct `labs()` statement for you. For example you could define an alternate `aes()` function which also assigns labels. And you can pass variable/labels as formulas. If you have the function

```
alt_aes1 <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  aess <- names(dots)
  vars <- sapply(dots, function(x) x[[2]])
  labels <- lapply(dots, function(x) x[[3]])
  list(
    do.call(aes, setNames(vars, aess)), 
    do.call(labs, setNames(labels, aess))
  )
}
```

Then you could call

```
ggplot(ir) + 
  alt_aes1(x=sep.len~"Sepal Length", y=sep.wid~"Sepal.Width", color=sp~"species") + 
  geom_point()
```

to get the same plot. Alternative you could use

```
alt_aes2 <- function(..., .rename=NULL) {
  dots <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...)
  list(
    do.call(aes, dots),
    if (!is.null(.rename)) do.call(labs, setNames(as.list(.rename[match(sapply(dots, deparse), names(.rename))]), names(dots)))
  )
}
```

which would be called like

```
ggplot(ir) + 
  alt_aes2(x=sep.len, y=sep.wid, color=sp, .rename=my_labels) + 
  geom_point()
```

Comment: thanks, that's really helpful. Could you give an example of what you had in mind when you said "create a helper function to build the correct labs() statement" please?

Comment: I added the example that create the `aes()` and `labs()` calls for you. It would kind of depend on your specific scenario how you wanted to create the helper function.

Comment: I love the creativity of `alt_aes`, but its syntax seems a bit...exotic

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, "exotic" is putting it mildly. I added a slightly less unusual  form as `alt_aes2`

Comment: @MrFlick Why do you say you wouldn't recommend your first approach (using `as_ggfun`)? After some testing it works really well! I also like `alt_aes2` but `alt_aes1` almost defeats the purpose as you have to name the variable each time anyway so lacks the automation side of things.