# Multiple line subplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am new to R and am struggling to understand how to create a matrix line plot (or plot with line subplots) given a data set with let's say one x and 5 y-columns such that:
-the first subplot is a plot of variables 1 and 2 (function of x)
-the second subplot variables 1 and 3 and so on
The idea is to use one of the variables (in this example  number 1) as a reference and pair it with the rest so that they can be easily compared.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: As a place to start, here's how to make a 2x2 matrix of line plots:  `par(mfrow=c(2,2)); plot(x=x, y=y1); plot(x=x, y=y2); ...`

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/q/55192983/786542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of one way to do that using `tidyr` and `ggplot`. `tidyr::gather` can pull the non-mpg columns into long format, each matched with its respective mpg. Then the data is mapped in `ggplot` so that x is mpg and y is the other value, and the name of the column it came from is mapped to facets.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  select(rowname, mpg, cyl, disp, hp) %>%
  gather(stat, value, cyl:hp) %>%
  ggplot(aes(mpg, value)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(stat~., scales = "free")
```

[image]