# Can I use pairs() function in R and plot a subset of the default plots?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to find the relationship between a selected target variable and the other variables in a data set. For example, if I consider the auto dataset I get the following plot. Assume my target variable is `mpg`

```
library("ISLR")
pairs(Auto)
```

[Image of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3HXU.png)

However, I would like to return only the first row of this plot since I'm only interested in plotting the relationship between the target variable and each of the other variables. I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55271354/11542679) which uses the `tidyverse` library and rearranges my dataframe.

I'm hoping there's a way to do it using just the `pairs()` function in R.

Edit: I'm looking for a way to keep the variable names in the final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for `horInd` and `verInd` in `?pairs`.

For instance

```
pairs(mtcars, verInd = 1, horInd = 2:ncol(mtcars))
```

Comment: Thanks. That actually answers the question I asked. However, I noticed that it takes off the names of the variables in the resultant plot. Any suggestion to avoid losing them?

Comment: @Hawklaz I don't think it's easy: `pairs` does not add labels to the plots except on the diagonal, so nothing is really taken off. Maybe there is a way with the `panel` argument (which is the function that makes each plot), but unless the variable name is passed as an argument, it won't be simple (maybe some trickery with a global variable?). I'll have a look.