# Maintain individual matrix names from a list in R

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a set of 94 matrices within a list in R. Each matrix is a different size; a sample is shown below:

```
 > summary(full_matrix)
            Length Class  Mode   
 Alex_1         64 -none- numeric
 Alex_10      2500 -none- numeric
 Alex_11      2916 -none- numeric
 Alex_12     20736 -none- numeric
 Alex_13     28900 -none- numeric
 Alex_14     62500 -none- numeric
 Alex_15     93025 -none- numeric
 Alex_2        100 -none- numeric
 Alex_3         25 -none- numeric
 Alex_4       1225 -none- numeric
 Alex_5       2304 -none- numeric
 Alex_6       1849 -none- numeric
```

I want to extract data from each matrix using `lapply()`. I'm performing a cluster analysis on each matrix, which generates a subset of clusters for each. I can do this using the following code:

```
 library(pvclust)

 clustering_data <- lapply(full_matrix, FUN = function(element) {
   result <- pvclust(element, method.dist="cor", method.hclust="average", nboot=1000, parallel=TRUE)
   output <- pvpick(result, alpha=0.95, pv="au", type="geq", max.only=TRUE)
   })
```

For `clustering_data[[1]]`, for example, this gives me:

```
 > clustering_data[[1]]
 $clusters
 $clusters[[1]]
 [1] "bah"   "hello" "huh"   "ooh"   "wee"   "woo"  

 $edges
 [1] 5
```

The problem is that I need to be able to identify the name of the original matrix (`Alex_1`, `Alex_2`, etc) from which the cluster is generated, and I can't figure out how to do this. I have done it for a previous `lapply()` function using `df %>% split(., f = .$var1)`, but I can't figure this out when the object is in a list.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950144/access-lapply-index-names-inside-fun especially the map/mapply option for  fairly long discussion of the issues here.

Comment: Thanks for this. I changer the `lapply()` chunk to the following `clustering_data <- mapply(FUN = function(list.elem) {...}, list.elem = full_matrix, names = n)` But I got the error `Error in (function (list.elem) : unused argument (names = dots[[2]][[1]])`. I'm completely new to lists and `lapply()` so am finding this quite hard to navigate! Could you provide a bit more input on how to structure the code?

Comment: Please give an example how your desired output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You should already have the output in `names` of `clustering_data`. Check :

```
names(clustering_data)
```

Or

```
clustering_data[1]
```

Comment: That didn't quite give me what I need, as rather than simply view the names, I want to attach them to each of the matrices in the list. This is what I did to sort the problem: `clustering_data_names <- sapply(clustering_data, `[`, "clusters")`

Comment: @CatherineLaing But I think your question was `I need to be able to identify the name of the original matrix (Alex_1, Alex_2, etc) from which the cluster is generated`. It doesn't give you name of the original matrix. Anyway, probably you meant `Map(cbind, names(full_matrix), sapply(clustering_data, \`[[\`, "clusters"))`