# lapply / purrr::map like function that allows access to the index by default?

Tags: r, lapply, purrr, sapply

There's a [workaround to allow access the index inside a s/lapply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9950217/5783745)

e.g.

```
x <- list(a=11,b=12,c=13) 
lapply(seq_along(x), function(y, n, i) { paste(n[[i]], y[[i]]) }, y=x, n=names(x))
```

Is there any function like s/lapply (or like `purrr::map()`) which allows access to the index in the simplest way possible, which I guess would be to simply supply its desired name to the initial function call and nothing more;

```
map_with_index <- function(.x, .f, index) {
  # Same as purrr::map()
  # ..but whatever string is provided to 'index' parameter becomes the index
  # and is accessible inside the function
  }
```

Does something already exist, or is it possible to define a custom function that does this?

Note: One could argue that the s/lapply technique above achieves what's required. But the counter argument is that it adds unwanted complexity even in its MRE, let alone in complicated real life settings, hence, a simplification would be valuable.

Comment: Do you need `Map(paste, names(x), x)` ? Or in your case perhaps `as.list(paste(names(x), x))`

Comment: @markus my first time seeing `Map` and I don't think it solves. Basically suppose I have a loop and wish to convert the process to a function so it can be used with lapply/map, but suppose there's some reason to need to know what iteration the loop is up to. Easy in a loop, but a little complicated using *apply/map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the `purrr::imap` family of functions. Here is a simple example:

```
set.seed(123)
s <- sample(10)
purrr::imap_chr(s, ~ paste0(.y, ": ", .x))
```

**Output**

```
[1] "1: 3"  "2: 10" "3: 2"  "4: 8"  "5: 6"  "6: 9"  "7: 1"  "8: 7"  "9: 5"  "10:4"
```

Comment: Wow. that is elegant. Is `.y` always the index and `.x` always the value?

Comment: Here I am using a formula shortcut. The first argument is always the value, the second argument  is always the position/name. Think about  `purrr::imap` as `purr::map2(x, seq_along(x), ...)` or `purr::map2(x, names(x), ...)`.

Comment: @slava-kohut good notice; never thought of passing index as a separate argument, manually

Comment: Worth noting that imap does not allow you to control whether the second argument is the position or name for a named vector; it always uses names when available.