# How to generate a named list containing vectors with repeating integers from a named list with character vectors in R?

Tags: r, list, lapply

Given is the list below. This list contains character vectors of variable length.

```
l1 <- list("a" = c("x1", "x2", "x3"),
           "b" = c("x4", "x5"),
           "c" = c("x6", "x7", "x8", "x9"))

> l1
$a
[1] "x1" "x2" "x3"

$b
[1] "x4" "x5"

$c
[1] "x6" "x7" "x8" "x9"
```

The desired output, let's call it `l2`, is the following:

```
$a
[1] 1 1 1

$b
[1] 2 2

$c
[1] 3 3 3 3
```

This output has the following characteristics:

- `l2` is a named list in which the names of the original list `l1` are preserved.
- The length of list `l2` is the same as list `l1`.
- The order of list elements in `l1` is preserved in `l2`.
- `l2` contains vectors with repeating integers. The length of each vector in `l2` is the same as the corresponding character vector in `l1`.

**Part of solution**

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950144/access-lapply-index-names-inside-fun?noredirect=1&lq=1) in which the statement below helped me to construct a partial solution.

> The usual work-around is to pass it the names or indices of the vector instead of the vector itself.

```
l2 <- lapply(X = seq_along(l1), 
             FUN = function(x) rep(x, times = length(l1[[x]]))) 
l2
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 3 3 3
```

All criteria are met, except that the names are not preserved in `l2`.

How can I fix this in one go (not using a seperate statement after the lapply statement)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you run your above code,, just add the code below:-

```
names(l2) <- names(l1)
```

This will assign the names of `l1` to `l2`, and hence, you will have the same names.

Edit: You can't achieve this with `lapply`, but you can do it with `sapply` by doing the following the following:-

```
l2 <- sapply(X = names(l1), 
         FUN = function(x) rep(which(names(l1) == x), times = length(l1[[x]])))

l2
$a
[1] 1 1 1

$b
[1] 2 2

$c
[1] 3 3 3 3
```

Turns out, if `X` argument of `sapply` is `character` vector, it will return the `list` by using `X` as names of the returned `list`.

Comment: Thanks Shawn Brar. This will do the job, but I prefer to do in one go using the lapply function. Any clues how to achieve this?

Comment: @PeterD, I have edited my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following base R option, using `lengths` + `rep` + `relist` like below

```
> relist(rep(seq_along(l1), lengths(l1)), l1)
$a
[1] 1 1 1

$b
[1] 2 2

$c
[1] 3 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[]` to preserve the names the list.

```
l1[] <- lapply(seq_along(l1), function(x) rep(x, times = length(l1[[x]]))) 
l1

#$a
#[1] 1 1 1

#$b
#[1] 2 2

#$c
#[1] 3 3 3 3
```

Another solution with `Map`.

```
l1[] <- Map(rep, seq_along(l1), lengths(l1))
```

In case you want to have another objects `l2` keeping `l1` as it is, create a copy of `l1` in `l2` by doing `l2 <- l1`.